# Setting up a webhosting at home with own domain

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, webserver, dynamic-dns

**FIRST OFF ALL:** I understand that hosting sites from home is a terrible idea, but the point is that I have to test some sites with a very custom apache/php setup so I don't want to spend money renting some custom VPS servers because I have a domain name which isn't used and I have a decent internet connection.

**The idea:**
I want to set up a DNS server behind my router (+port forwards) and point my domains nameservers to my dns server behind my router. (the dynamic ip could be resolved with [Duck dns](https://www.duckdns.org/)).
After that i want to set up a few sub domains for apache and a mail server.

- Could this setup work or it is a completely bad idea?
- If it could work which DNS server is the good choice and how can I set up the DNS records for the mail and apache servers?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a DNS server behind your router at all, and I don't really think it'll work that way.

You'd want to point your domain name(s) at your main ip addresses, and redirect traffic *per protocol* as needed. Mail may not work, since a lot of mail blacklists block dynamic ip addresses.

What you really need to do is to set up *one* mail server, servicing different domains (postfix would do this) or alternately a [smarthost](https://serverfault.com/questions/559655/postfix-msa-smarthost-and-lan), and one http reverse_proxy (ngnix is what people tend to prefer) to handle passing on web traffic to the appropriate web servers.

An alternative for the web side of things is ipv6, with cloudflare to handle web traffic redirection. This worked great for me, but of course, I have no idea how a pure ipv6 mail server would work.